# How to calculate the size of scroll bar thumb?

Tags: c#, user-interface, xna, scroll

I'm making my own custom UI system for my game in C# and XNA, and I have a small problem with scroll bars. I don't know what is the equation to calculate the thumb size of the scroll bar.

So let's say I have a panel that is 200x200 px. and an image that is 600x600 px. How can I calculate the scroll bar thumb size according to the image size?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The thumb (I've heard people call it a scrubber) size should be the size of the viewport (in your example 200px) divided by the size of the content (600px).

So, your thumb should take up 1/3rd the available height.  The available height is the size of the scroll bar minus the arrows.

For example, if each arrow is 25px, then the thumb size would be calculated as so.

```
var arrowHeight = 25;
var viewportHeight = 200;
var contentHeight = 600;

var viewableRatio = viewportHeight / contentHeight; // 1/3 or 0.333333333n

var scrollBarArea = viewportHeight - arrowHeight * 2; // 150px

var thumbHeight = scrollBarArea * viewableRatio; // 50px
```

Of course you will have to make your own checks if the content height is smaller than the viewable area, if the content height is 0, etc.

Comment: Uhhm, thanks for this but, how about calculating the content step of scrollbar, can you give me the formula?

Comment: what do you mean by content step?

Comment: He saying if he want to jump 1 pixel to down then how much content scrolled down.

Answer (score 8):

Please find following Answer for your Question **"how about calculating the content step of scrollbar, can you give me the formula?"**

*Formula for calculating the content step of scroller*

```
var scrollTrackSpace = self.contentHeight - self.viewportHeight; // (600 - 200) = 400 
var scrollThumbSpace =  self.viewportHeight - self.thumbHeight; // (200 - 50) = 150
var scrollJump = scrollTrackSpace / scrollThumbSpace; //  (400 / 150 ) = 2.666666666666667
```

If you **jump down 1 pixel thumb** then your **content should scroll 2.666666666666667 pixel up.**

Please do let me know if you would require more help.

Comment: Wow! Many many thanks! I'm very glad somebody notices my comment and mention an answer. Yes! I have a lots of question about those but, not for now I think? Maybe next month? or the other month? Thanks again I really really appreciate it :D

Comment: Your answer helped me building a custom scrollbar to my Gui, thank you! I tried to reproduce your calcs to also build a custom scrollbar to a `Listbox`, but its not matching with how windows calculate the rows/thumb position. If you could take a look at my profile, i created a question about it, thanks!