# How to keep a custom scrollbar proportional to the visible content in a graph?

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, custom-controls

### Problem Statement

I've been working on a custom grid control whose viewport is exactly of size **1024** **pixels** which is used to plot signal points. Note that a complete signal also consist of exactly **1024 points**. This means that one signal spread to the whole width of the grid.

I can also zoom into the graph which increases the **Signal points** times **ZoomFactor**. which is:

```
...
const int SignalLength = 1024;
int ZoomFactor = 2;    //Updated by user
int NewPoints = SignalLength * ZoomFactor;
...
```

I've been trying to create custom scrubber/scroller which helps in scrolling through a zoomed signal. However, I've been facing issues during maintaining the proportions of scroll and visible content in sync.

---

### Visual Example [ZoomFactor: 2]

[image]

A few parameters that I've worked are:

- **Scroll Buttons** : Each of Size **50x50** pixels
- **Scrollable Area**: Which reduces due to Scroll buttons. That is `Grid Width - (50*2)`: **924** pixels.
- **Scrubber Width** : Which will always be `Scrollable Area / ZoomFactor`

Notice the arrows in image which shows the visible section of signal is not in sync with the scrubber. I guess the scrubber is moving too fast than what the grid is actually showing.

---

### Code

```
private void ZoomFactor_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ZoomFactor > 1)
    {
        Scrubber.Width = (ScrubberTrackPanel.Width / ZoomFactor);
        ScrubberWidth.Text = Scrubber.Width.ToString();
        ScrubberTrackPanel.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ScrubberTrackPanel.Visible = false;
        Scrubber.Width = Scrubber.Parent.Width;
    }
}

private void SfBtn_GridScrollRight_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   // Both left and right button's tag property have the step value.
   // Left has -2 
   // Right has 2
   GlobalVars.GridScrubStepSize = 0 + int.Parse((SfButton)sender).Tag.ToString());
   GridScrubberTimer.Start();
}

private void GridScrubberTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScrollGrid(GlobalVars.GridScrubStepSize);
}

private void ScrollGrid(int StepSize)
{
   var newStepPos = GlobalVars.ZoomedSignalLeft + StepSize;
   //To stop scroll timer if any of the boundry (left/right) of graph is reached.
   if (newStepPos <= 0 || newStepPos >= 1024 * ZoomFactor && GridScrubberTimer.Enabled)
   {
       GridScrubberTimer.Stop();
       return;
   }
   var ZoomedSignalSlice = GlobalVars.ZoomedSignal.Skip(newStepPos).Take(1024).ToList();
   if (ZoomedSignalSlice.Count == 1024)
   {
       GlobalVars.ZoomedSignalLeft += GlobalVars.GridScrubStepSize;
       if (ScrubberTrackPanel.Visible)
       {
           Scrubber.Location = new Point(Scrubber.Location.X + (int)Math.Floor(GlobalVars.GridScrubStepSize/ (float)ZoomFactor), 0);
           ScrubberCords.Text = Scrubber.Location.ToString();
       }
       GraphGrid.Refresh();
   }
}
```

---

### Tried Solutions

I've tried [How to calculate the size of scroll bar thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366795/how-to-calculate-the-size-of-scroll-bar-thumb) and [Formula for content step of scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035363/formula-for-content-step-of-scrollbar) but somehow I'm not able to grasp the proportions correctly.

I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious (&& stupid :p) thing which you will shed light on.

Comment: are you shure this is not just an effect of the streching of the graph?
it looks like almost perfectly algined to me

Comment: @DenisSchaf I'm sure it's not about stretching of graph because there is one thing I noticed that the maximum travel of the scrubber should be within bounds of `ScrubberTrackPanel` which is not happening and the **X** is travelling more than that. What I'm saying is that at max Scrubber's X should be half of Track's width which will be `924/2` : **462**. But the scrubber is travelling till **511**.

Comment: What I want is to map the movement of scrubber from **[0 to 1023 ]** into **[0 to 963]**. That is where I am failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering a lot with the code for hours I realized the calculation for the location was very wrong. After fixing it, the scroll is working as expected while maintaining the proportions appropriately.

Below is the correct code:

```
...
GlobalVars.ZoomedSignalLeft += GlobalVars.GridScrollStepSize;
// Mapping the current beginning position of the visible signal on the grid in the range of ScrollerTrackPanel and then dividing 
// it with the ZoomFactor To get location of scrubber over the signal image proportional to the visible signal on the grid.
int newx = (int)Math.Floor(GlobalVars.ZoomedSignalLeft / 1024F * ScrollerTrackPanel.Width / ZoomFactor);
Scrubber.Location = new Point(newx, 0);
...
```